# Different ways of initializing an object in c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, initialization

Imagine this class:

```
class Entity {
public:
    int x, y;
    
    Entity() : x(0), y(0) { }
    Entity(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { }
}
```

And here are multiple ways of initializing the class with what I think I know:

```
Entity ent1;                //Uses the default constructor, so x=0 and y=0
Entity ent2();              //Uses the default constructor, so x=0 and y=0 (Not sure)
Entity ent3(1, 2);          //Made constructor, so x=1 and y=2
Entity ent4 = Entity();     //Default constructor, so x=0 and y=0
Entity ent5 = Entity(2, 3); //Made constructor, so x=2 and y=3
```

I know that's it's possible to make an object on the heap memory, but that's not what I am looking for at this moment.

My question is, what's the difference between these ways of initializing an object?

I'm not sure which one I should use when.

Comment: `Entity ent2();` is a function declaration.

Comment: So what does that mean? the x and y values aren't set?

Comment: No, this means there exists no `Entity` at all, `ent2` is a function.

Comment: No, it means you are declaring a function called `ent2` that returns an `Entity`.

Comment: Ohh ok, so ent2 isn't a valid form of initializing an object

Comment: ok, so I understand how ent2 works now then

Comment: you can use {} in C++11 and later. Look up uniform initialization. Examples you offered are C++87  (and there MVP probably could allow a varable ent2, compilers were not consistent)

Comment: @Swift You meant to say "C++98" (or "C++03"), *not* "C++87" - there is no such thing ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl C++87 is a "nickname" of pre-ISO C++. C++ coming from 1979-1985 years, first compiler for personal computer I used was from 87. First  IEC 14882 C++ was from 1998

Comment: @Swift Well, your personal nicknames are really not that useful to other people here. More likely to just confuse than anything else.

Comment: @JesperJuhl that's not my "personal" nickname. it's based on Stroustroup's books first issue. Essentially languge he described in 1986-1987 first IS C++87 . Because there was no other description

Comment: Handy reading on this subject: https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

Comment: Also don't forget `Entity ent6{};` and `Entity ent7{1, 2};`

Comment: @ user4581301 those things should be part of some kind of "cheat sheet" for novices. Along with rule of 5\rule of zero, etc. Best with drawings :P

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The difference in initialization lies not only in form it takes, but also
in type of entity which is being initialized. In this case it's a class-type object with a defined default constructor, as well as a constructor with parameters.

```
Entity ent1;
```

The statement above is default initialization which result in a call of default constructor for the class `Entity`.

---

```
Entity ent2();
```

The declaration above will be treated by compiler as a function prototype if that's possible. `Entity` would be returned type of a function `ent2`, which takes no arguments. It's known as a case of *most vexing parse* (MVP) and its existence led to appearance of misleading "clever dumb rule": "never use parenthesis".

---

In statement like this a user-defined constructor that matches list of arguments is invoked for `ent3` object:

```
Entity ent3(1, 2);    // calls Entity(int x, int y)
```

Another case where MVP can strike is something like this:

```
Entity ent3_1(int(a), int(b));  // It's not what it looks like.
```

`ent3_1` above is not a variable. The statement declares a function with two int parameters. `int(a)` being same as `int a` is legacy of C language and declaration syntax there, which ignores "extra" parenthesis.

---

```
Entity ent4 = Entity();
```

`ent4` is a ***proper*** version of `ent2` case until C++11. Default constructor is invoked as part of value initialization. Its form allows to avoid an ambiguity solving principle which makes `ent2` and `ent3_1` incorrect. Equal sign here is not an assignment, for no `operator=` call  will happen here. It's part of declaration syntax meant to markup the initialization expression.

---

```
Entity ent5 = Entity(2, 3);
```

`ent5` is a version of ent3 case. User-defined constructor invoked as part of value initialization.

---

Your question is tagged as C++11, and C++11 allows uniform initialization syntax:

```
Entity ent12{};     // This is a legal alternative of ent2 case
Entity ent13{1, 2}; // A call to constructor or member initialization
Entity ent13{ int(a), int(b) }; // Not a function anymore
Entity ent14 = {};              // Not an assignment
Entity ent15 = Entity{2, 3};    // Not an assignment either!
```

Note that uniform initialization syntax has a caveat. E.g. this line

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
```

declares a vector of 10 elements. But this one

```
std::vector<int> v{10};
```

declares a vector initialized with single element of type int with value 10. This happens because `std::vector` has a constructor with following signature defined:

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

In case that you can't use neither () without triggering MVP nor {} without invoking undesired constructor, the value initialization assignment syntax allows to resolve the issue.

Addendum: Must watch [CppCon 2018: Nicolai Josuttis “The Nightmare of Initialization in C++”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs&t=2706s)

Comment: could you please explain more about the difference between `()` and `{}` related to how should I get that the program interpret them differently? And is it possible for my own class to have a constructor that does something when called with `{}` and something else when called with `()`?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu The difference between () or {} is supplying parameters vs. uniform initialization. The example how this may lead to different behavior is actually given above but that's completely separate question to ask. You can't do that with arbitrary form of brace content. Defining constructor that takes `std::initializer_list<T>` is the key to the trick above, because initialization list's elements of type T will be bound to  that proxy class by default. Abuse of this may lead to a mess.

Comment: Nice answer, but I'm missing the point about the `= ...` forms requiring the existence and accessibility of a copy constructor, even when that copy constructor call is elided.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica does it actually? https://wandbox.org/permlink/CNYt9MBNllYPP1aY

Comment: My compiler says "yes". At least up to C++11. You need to delete the default copy constructor to test this.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica  Oh, on old standards! it seem not to be elided during initialization, have to pore through standard

Comment: The point is, that, at least in the old standards, it doesn't matter whether the copy can be elided or not, the copy constructor must be present and accessible because the copy is part of the semantics. I.e. the compiler checks that the copy constructor is present and accessible, and only when that test is positive does it proceed to elide the call to the copy constructor. I think they have changed / planned to change this in the newest standards, but up to C++11, I have verified that it's still the case.

Comment: I created a class where I have the *copy move constructor* deleted (using C++11 syntax). Now only *ent3* works, but *ent5* throws a compile error. I don't know what's going on and I have no idea what to search for!

Comment: @ShuvoSarker you _explicitly_ deleted them, not implicitly and not just made them unavailable (ie. protected/private). syntax of ent5 still requires at least move one present in semantics. C+11 and below requires them to be accessible.

Comment: What will  Entity* ent; do? Somehow, when I do Entity* ent; a new object is not getting created, while Entity* ent = new Entity(); creates a new object and a corresponding pointer. The first one seems explainable as I am just creating a pointer. But shouldn't new Entity() create a new Enitity object and not an Enitity* (a pointer)?

Comment: @levio_sa in statement like that no assignment is happening (aka, no assignment operator), modern C++ also had guaranteed that no copy happen either. It's a know paradox that "= is not assignment here". Yes, new expression allocates memory and constructs the object, the value returned by expression is used to initialize pointer. And pointer is an a variable, created by the declaration. Depending on what type the variable is of, it's either an object or not, e.g. a reference is a variable but not an object. I suggest you to watch this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs