# Candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument

Tags: c++, class, oop, instantiation, copy-constructor

## The problem

I have a `Deck` class which is a container for 52 `Card` objects. `Deck` is derived from another class called `CardCollection` (since I want similar groups of Cards elsewhere that are not a full deck of cards). My Problem is that I can create a `Deck` object using

```
Deck deck();
```

But when I use

```
Deck deck = Deck();
```

Clang-tidy (in CLion) complains that `Candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument`. My understanding (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802012/different-ways-of-initializing-an-object-in-c/49802943) question was that these two ways of instantiating were basically the same, but since one causes warnings

## The Code

I'll only paste the constructors of these class declarations to prevent this beign a "wall-o-text" question.

```
//Card.h

    class Card {
    public:
        int rank; 
        basic_string<char> suit;

        Card(int r, std::string s); // rank and suit

        ~Card();

    //...
}
```

```
// CardCollection.h
#include <vector>
#include "Card.h"


class CardCollection {

protected:
    vector<Game::Card> _cards;
public:
    CardCollection();
     ~CardCollection();
     CardCollection(CardCollection &other);
     explicit CardCollection(int n);
     explicit CardCollection(vector<Game::Card> &cards);
    //...
```

and

```
// Deck.h

#include "Card.h"
#include <vector>
#include "CardCollection.h"

class Deck : public CardCollection {
public:
    Deck();
    ~Deck();
    explicit Deck(vector<Game::Card> &cards);
    Deck * shuffle();
    //...
};
```

Comment: You need to implement a copy constructor. And if you also want just `deck = Deck()` (i.e., not upon declaration), then also an assignment operator.

Comment: Ah, I thought that it would be derived from `CardCollection`?

Comment: And `Deck deck();` is a function declaration.

Comment: Also your copy constructor should be

`CardCollection(const CardCollection& other);`

Comment: Constructors are not inherited, so you need to explicitly define copy constructor in subclass even if superclass already has copy constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters this

```
Deck deck();
```

is a function declaration that has no parameters and has the return type `Deck`.

Secondly the copy constructor of the class CardCollection

```
CardCollection(CardCollection &other);
```

can not bind the non-constant reference to a temporary object.

Declare it like

```
CardCollection( const CardCollection &other);
```