# What's the difference between the two ways to create an instance of a class in C++?

Tags: java, c++, class, oop, constructor

Let's say I have a class named `Foo`, which has a parameterized constructor `Foo(int a, int b, int c)`.

What's the difference between these two ways to create an instance of `Foo`?

```cpp
Foo f = Foo(1, 2, 3);
```

and

```cpp
Foo f(1, 2, 3);
```

I know in Java it would just be:

```java
Foo f = new Foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different ways of initializing an object in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802012/different-ways-of-initializing-an-object-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The statement `Foo f(1, 2, 3);` constructs a `Foo` object named `f` via [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

*Prior* to C++17, the statement `Foo f = Foo(1, 2, 3);` creates a temporary `Foo` object via direct initialization, and then copy-constructs the `f` object from that temporary via [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

*Since* C++17, there is NO DIFFERENCE between the two statements.  Due to guaranteed [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), the statement `Foo f = Foo(1, 2, 3);` is treated *identical* to `Foo f(1, 2, 3);`, avoiding the creation of any temporary `Foo` object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using new operator with the constructor will return the address for the allocated memory for the created instance, after calling the constructor of the class.

So: `Foo f = new Foo(1, 2, 3);` is not the same in C++ : but you can call the new operator as follow :

```
Foo* f = new Foo(1, 2, 3);
```

For the first part of your question : I think the difference is of the order of steps building.
`Foo f(1, 2, 3)` : here, the f instance is built directly.
`Foo f = Foo(1, 2, 3)` : here there are different steps in the instance building :
first, a temporary instance is created and call the constructor
second, this temporary instance is assign to f by calling the operator=

It's like ask what the difference between:
`int x = 5`; =>here 5 is directly assign
and `int x = 2+3;` => first 2+3 is perform, and then the result is assigned to x.

Comment: “*I think the difference is of the order of steps building.*” - what you described was true before C++17. But in C++17, the rules were changed, so `Foo f(1,2,3)` and `Foo f = Foo(1,2,3)` are *identical*. “*this temporary instance is assign to f by calling the operator=*” - that is just plain wrong. The `f` object is constructed by passing the temporary to `Foo`’s copy constructor, not its assignment operator.

Comment: You are right about the copy-ctor call!