# Base class default constructor in derived class constructor initializer list

Tags: c++, constructor, derived-class, default-constructor

I have seen a lot of times people adding the default constructor of base class in the derived class constructor initializer list like so

```
DerivedClass::DerivedClass(int x) : BaseClass(), member_derived(x)
{
    //Do something;
}
```

Derived class constructor by default calls the default constructor of base class. Is the `BaseClass()` in the above initializer list redundant?

Comment: If it's somebody else's code I'm reading, there is no way to tell apart an *intentionally omitted* base class initializer from a *forgotten* one. Some folks take to being explicit and write "redundant" things for that reason.

Comment: Writing down the base class constructor invocation does *not* cause the default constructor being called twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on declaration of base class. Constructor of derived class actually *initializes* base class. It involves default constructor call if such is present. If base class is trivial, it wouldn't be initialized. Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
   int c;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
   Derived() : Base()
   {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    std::cout << d.c << std::endl;
}
```

If you would comment `: Base()` out, you may get compiler warning, or a random value printed.

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:17:20: warning: 'd.Derived::<anonymous>.Base::c' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
   17 |     std::cout << d.c << std::endl;
      |                    ^
prog.cc:16:13: note: 'd' declared here
   16 |     Derived d;
```

in this case `: Base()` ensures value initialization of `Base`

Comment: When you say `If base class is trivial`, do you mean its members are POD types?

Comment: @ontherocks no. POD is a more strict definition, because it supposes a standard memory layout, i.e. no non-static members with various access or inline initialization or spread across different classes, or virtual base classes , virtual members, no  multiple members of base type. Trivial in this case is enough to be trivially constructed, i.e. no constructor defined by user (even as `default`) and no inline initialization of non-statics. In general trivial means that no special functions are defined by user.

Comment: Doing `Derived() : Base()` initializes `int c` to what value? Zero? I have seen people using the syntax `Derived() : Base{}` instead of `Derived() : Base()`. Are both of these syntax interchangeable?

Comment: @ontherocks kinda, when empty. () assumes constructor call or default initialization, {} is initializer. The  latter is called "uniform initialization". If you don't have constructor, you can use {} to supply list of values to initialize members. If you have constructor, there goes list of arguments.Must watch, imho: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

Comment: @ontherocks There also was such question (my answer is kind of dated  though) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802012/different-ways-of-initializing-an-object-in-c

Comment: It's not just when the base class is trivial. Value initialization will zero-initialize the object when the default constructor is not user-provided.

Answer (score 1):

It's redundant to explicitly mention the base class default constructor in a derived class's initialization list. But if doing so makes you feel good, feel free to do it.